# 'Cannot switch to old mode now' Error in Elasticdump

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I tried backing up and restoring an index to json in Elasticsearch using elasticdump (on Node.js):

[Backup]
`elasticdump --input=http://cred:entials@myserver.com:9200/.kibana --output=kibana.json --type=data`
(Works)

[Restore]
`elasticdump --output=http://cred:entials@myserver.com:9200/.kibana --input=kibana.json --type=data` (Gives an error)

The error is:

```
_stream_readable.js:749
    throw new Error('Cannot switch to old mode now.');
          ^
Error: Cannot switch to old mode now.
    at emitDataEvents (_stream_readable.js:749:11)
    at ReadStream.Readable.pause (_stream_readable.js:740:3)
    at file.completeBatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/elasticdump/lib/transports/file.js:75:19)
    at Stream.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/elasticdump/lib/transports/file.js:65:10)
    at Stream.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at drain (/usr/lib/node_modules/elasticdump/node_modules/through/index.js:34:23)
```

Does anyone know what is going and how to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your node version is outdated.

Try running `node --version` and if you get anything below 1.0.0 then you need to upgrade your local version of node.

In order to manage several node versions locally you can use the [`n` module](https://github.com/tj/n). Simply run the below steps

```
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

And then you'll have the latest version of node installed and elasticdump will work again.

Comment: Were you able to try this out?

Comment: Updating the node version worked, but I did it following the instructions on the node site.

Comment: Could you please validate the answer in this case? It helps for searching answers when they are flagged as resolved : )

Comment: `n latest` fails for me: "Error: invalid version"